# defining a new notation

Tags: equations

To show the direct limit, I know some ways but I wish to write this inductive limit using a new command, `\limind`? In other words, when writing this new command I want to see this: `limind`, not in italic form.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you are loading `\usepackage{amsmath}` (and you should anyway), with `\DeclareMathOperator*{\limind}{lim\,ind}` you should be OK.

Comment: @egreg, I won by one minute. `:-D`

Comment: @Gaussler This was a clear duplicate.

Comment: Details, details...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*\limind{lim\, ind}
\begin{document}
$\limind_{n\to\infty} a_n$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may remove the `\,` if you don't want a space between `lim` and `ind`.

Comment: Does this give the proper `\displaystyle` behavior?

Comment: Yes, if you remember the `*` (I hope I remember its position correctly).

Comment: Ah!  I learn something new every day.

Comment: I'm surprised I could teach *you* anything about LaTeX. `;-)`

Comment: The more I know, the more I realize I don't know.